# How to compute $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{x^2}-\cos{(2x)}-3x^2}{x^2\sin{x^2}}$ limits by using taylor series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation, taylor-expansion

How to compute $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{x^2}-\cos{(2x)}-3x^2}{x^2\sin{x^2}}$ limits by using taylor series?

I think that we need to take every familiar taylor series (i.e. $e^x,\sin{x}$) and expand them to certain order (or power of $x$). So the major question I have is how many terms do I have to expand, to $x^2$ or something else?

$e^x=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{x^n}{n!}$, $\sin{x}=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a starting point you may expand any elementary functions to a power which may delete with the denominator. I'll explain clearer:
the denominator is the simplest in terms of composition of functions, $x^2sin(x^2) = x^2(x^2+o(x^2))=x^4+o(x^4)$. Now let's try to reach the same exponent on the numerator: $e^{x^2}-cos(2x)-3x^2 = 1+x^2+\frac{x^4}{2}+o(x^4)-(1-\frac{(2x)^2}{2}+\frac{(2x)^4}{4!}+o(x^4))-3x^2=x^2(1+2-3)+x^4(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2}{3})+o(x^4)=-\frac{1}{6}x^4+o(x^4)$

Now gather both the information
$\frac{-\frac{1}{6}x^4+o(x^4)}{x^4+o(x^4)} \underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\rightarrow} -\frac{1}{6}$.
Personally, to be sure to have done right, I try to put some small numbers on a calculator or Matlab, Octave whatelse and compare the result!

Answer (score 1):

In the denominator you have $x^2 \sin x^2$. So the lowest order in $x$ after using Taylor expansion is $x^4$.
$$x^2 \sin x^2 = x^2 (x^2+o(x^4))=x^4+o(x^6)$$
Because of that you should investigate behavior of the numerator up to the fourth order.
$$e^{x^2}-\cos 2x - 3x^2=(1+x^2+\frac{1}{2}x^4+o(x^6))-(1-\frac{1}{2}(2x)^2+\frac{1}{4!}(2x)^4+o(x^6))-3x^2=
\\=x^4(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2}{3})+o(x^6)=-\frac{1}{6}x^4+o(x^6)$$
Now you can easily compute the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Without going to Taylor series it's simple to justify replacing $\sin x^2$ with $x^2.$ To finish the problem, recall the Taylor approximations $e^u = 1 + u + u^2/2 +O(u^3), \cos u = 1 -u^2/2 + u^4/4! +O(u^6)$ as $u\to 0.$